# Pyodide languagePluginLoader is not defined

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, pyodide

I have been using Pyodide to run some python in my website. It has been working up until recently, however now has begin giving this error,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: languagePluginLoader is not defined
at 2347:162
```

Some searching has revealed that this method is deprecated in pyodide anyway

https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/js-api.html#globalThis.loadPyodide

and Insteasd of using languagePluginUrl I should  use loadPyodide.

I have no idea how to do this, I know nothing of js, only python,

My code is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    languagePluginLoader.then(() => {
    pyodide.loadPackage(['numpy']).then(() => {
        pyodide.runPython(`   


    # My python code here


      `);
  });});

</script>
```

This used to work fine, so I think I just need to use the new method. Any help converting it to the new method appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using a newer version of pyodide. Since 0.18.0, you should use `loadPyodide` with the pyodide base url instead, which gives the `pyodide` object in the callback:

```
const PYODIDE_BASE_URL = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.0/full"

loadPyodide({ indexURL: PYODIDE_BASE_URL }).then((pyodide) => {
  globalThis.pyodide = pyodide      // you might also want to store pyodide globally so 
                                    // so you can access anywhere in the scope
  pyodide.loadPackage(['numpy']).then(() => {
    pyodide.runPython(`   
    # My python code here
  `);
});});
```

Comment: That solved the specific issue. I really appreciate it. I do need to make some more code changes also due to the newer pyodide, which when I figure out what they are I will update here for other searchers. In the meantime this really helped. :)

Comment: i cant download and store this files locally?